# How to set drawable image in textview with top + left (not only top,not only left) in android?

Tags: textview

I want to set an `ImageView` to be in the top left of a `TextView` using the `android:drawable` property.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think using a [9patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) is the way to go. Just keep the top left corner as a constant non resizeable part.

Comment: Thanks @torque203, This idea is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 9 Patch image for this.